# How I can pass array of objects as params in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have array of object with same key name. I want to pass each `address` key inside that object as parameter to my api. How I can do this ? I get response like this `{ '0': { address: 'abcd' }, '1': { address: 'xyz' } }`.

```js
const getDataWithAddress = async ({ ...address }) => {
        // console.log(address);
        const res = await transport.post(`${api}/get`, address);
        console.log(res);
        // return res
}

getDataWithAddress([{ address: 'abcd'}, { address: 'xyz' }])
```

Comment: What is "my API", exactly? Do you mean a RESTful web-service, or a JavaScript library? What is `transport`, exactly?

Comment: We don't know what format your API expects the data to be presented in, so we can't tell you how to encode the data in that format.

Comment: yeah its rest api

Comment: Most likely duplicate of: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in your question, it looks like you want to make `n` requests for `n` address objects. However, it looks like your request function only takes one address at a time.

```js
const getDataWithAddress = async (address) => {
    const res = await transport.post(`${api}/get`, address);
    return res;
}

const myAddresses = [{ address: "abc" }, { address: "xyz" }];

// Wait for an aggregate of Promises.
const results = await Promise.all(
    // Turn each address object into a REST API request for that object.
    myAddresses.map(addObj => getDataWithAddress(addObj.address))
);

console.log(results);
// Whatever your expected API results are.
// [{ AddressObject: { ... } }, { AddressObject: { ... } }]
```